# java.time get first day of selected month

Tags: java

I am trying to get day of week of first day in selected month. Main condition is use only java.time. I need smth like this:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).getDayOfWeek();
```

I already have YearMonth, which i got by entering numbers of year and month. How can i get dayOfWeek of first day in month ? I did it like this:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = yearMonth.atDay(1).getDayOfWeek();
```

but i got a commentary, that i have "magic numbers" that i need eliminate by correct using library java.time.

Answer (score 4):

## Magic number

> i got a commentary, that i have "magic numbers" that i need eliminate by correct using library java.time.

No, you did not use a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)); that commentary is incorrect. The author of that commentary jumped too fast upon seeing a hard-coded literal number being passed as an argument. Indeed, passing a literal number as an argument is suspicious as a possible “magic number”, and worthy of a second look, but in this case is quite appropriate.

The term [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) refers to the use of numbers whose purpose/meaning/role is not immediately obvious. Passing `1` to `YearMonth.atDay()` is quite obvious, meaning the first of the month.

Personally I *do* wish the `YearMonth` class offered a `atFirstOfMonth` like it has `atEndOfMonth`. My motivation is to avoid this very problem: Being sensitive to spotting hard-coded literal number passed as argument. But no big deal. **Your code’s call to `atDay( 1 )` is correct and clear.** Using a `TemporalAdjuster` is correct as well, but is not as obvious.

One-liner, if you like short code (I do not):

```
YearMonth.of( year , month ).atDay( 1 ).getDayOfWeek()
```

Some discussion follows to elucidate this topic.

## `YearMonth`

> I already have YearMonth, which i got by entering numbers of year and month.

Java offers a class for this, to represent an entire month: [`YearMonth`](http://I%20already%20have%20YearMonth,%20which%20i%20got%20by%20entering%20numbers%20of%20year%20and%20month.).

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now() ;  // Capture the current year-month as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

I recommend passing objects of this class around your codebase rather than using mere integer numbers for year & month. Using objects provides type-safety, ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.

## Time zone

Better to specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. Better to explicitly specify the desired/expected time zone than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default which can change at any moment during runtime.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Specify desired/expected time zone. Or explicitly ask for JVM’s current default: `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current year-month as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (time zone).
```

## `LocalDate`

Get the date of the first day of month as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;  // Get the first day of the month.
```

## `DayOfWeek`

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum provides seven pre-existing objects, one for each day of the week. These are *not* mere strings, but are smart objects.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Generate a String representing the name of this day-of-week localized to the human language and cultural norms of a particular `Locale`.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the month and the year and you just need the first day of the month I would do something like this:

```
DayOfWeek firstDay = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).getDayOfWeek();
```

Basically, you build a date where the `dayOfMonth` param is 1.

Based on your solution for the first day of a month assuming `yearMonth` is a `LocalDate` this should work:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek =yearMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

Comment: why do i need current date for getting dayOfWeek of first day of (for example) january 1997 ?

Comment: @IlyaTomashenko you don't; I used now as an example

Comment: looks good, but, `yearMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())` return `YearMonth` and doesn't has `.getDayOfWeek()`, i wouldn't ask, if it was so easy. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @IlyaTomashenko are you importing yoda time instead of java; works for me and I just copied it from ide

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution by just passing an LocalDate object:

```
public static String getFirstWeekDay(LocalDate date) {

        int day = 1;
        int month = date.getMonthValue();
        int year = date.getYear();

        LocalDate newDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        String dayOfWeek = newDate.getDayOfWeek().toString();

        return dayOfWeek;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the method below to get the DayOfWeek Enum:

```
public static DayOfWeek getFirstWeekDay(LocalDate date){

        int day = 1;
        int month = date.getMonthValue();
        int year = date.getYear();

        LocalDate newDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

        return newDate.getDayOfWeek();
}
```

I hope this helps.